# C# List<[ThreeDimensionalObject]>.Find("ValueOfFirstElement") and Return "ValueOfSecondElement"

Tags: c#

I've searched in vain mainly because I don't think I know what to look for.  I think I need to use the `Find` method for Lists in C# to do what I want, but I can't seem to get it right.  This leads me to think one of two obvious scenarios is happening:

1)  I'm going about this the wrong way (my money is on this one).

2)  I'm going about this the right way, but I just don't understand the syntax for finding something.

Also, just to answer some of the "Why are you..." or "Why haven't you..." questions:  If you can't tell, I'm figuring this out as I go along - and this is about the extent of what I've been able to teach myself thus far.

Here is what I'm trying to do:
First, I have a `list<FitHeaderCard>` object called `HeaderBlock`. and it is populated by this custom type:

```
public class FitHeaderCard
{
  public string keyword;
  public string value;
  public string comment;

  //Constructor
  public FitHeaderCard()
  {}

  public FitHeaderCard(string fitHeaderCard)
  {  // input:  80 byte string containing 3 fixed width delimited values.
    keyword = fitHeaderCard.Substring(0, 8).Trim();
    value = fitHeaderCard.Substring(10, 20).Trim();
    comment = fitHeaderCard.(33,47).Trim();
  }

  public FitHeaderCard(FitHeaderCard fitHeaderCard)
  {  //clone a FitHeaderCard
    keyword = fitHeaderCard.keyword;
    value = fitHeaderCard.value;
    comment = fitHeaderCard.comment;
  }
}
```

The header cards are fed into a list when read from a file on my hard drive (using a BinaryReader).

The `FitHeader` object code is as follows:

```
public class FitHeader
{
  public string headerCard;
  public string headerSize;
  public FitHeaderCard fitHeaderCard = new FitHeaderCard();
  public List<FitHeaderCard> HeaderBlock = new List<FitHeaderCard>();

  //Constructor
  public FitHeader()
  {
  }

  public FitHeader(string _headerCard)
  {
    headerCard = _headerCard;
  }

  public FitHeaderCard FitHeaderCard 
  {
    get; 
    private set;
  }

  //Methods
  public void AddHeaderCard(string _headerCard)
  {
    FitHeaderCard = new FitHeaderCard(_headerCard);
    HeaderBlock.Add(FitHeaderCard);
  }

  public List<FitHeaderCard> GetHeader()
  {
    return HeaderBlock;
  }

  public int GetHeaderSize();
  {
    return headerSize = //some convoluted math but it works!
  }

  //This is what I'm having trouble with
  public FitHeaderCard GetFitHeaderCard(string _keyword)
  {
    HeaderBlock.Find("BITPIX");
    fitHeaderCard = new FitHeaderCard(fitHeaderCard); // clone constructor
    return fitHeaderCard;
  }
}
```

So the `GetFitHeaderCard` method is supposed to take in a keyword, and return the the entire FitHeaderCard object found in the HeaderBlock list.

Optionally, I'd love to just get the Value back, possibly in a separate method, but for now, I can live with just referencing the value of `FitHeaderCard.Value`

Thanks in advance for your help!  I look forward to face palming myself when an elegant and obvious answer is revealed to this newbie .Net coder!

Comment: You're not capturing the result of `HeaderBlock.Find`.

Comment: I have an intellisense error:  Argument 1:  cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Predicate<Fit.Types.FitHeaderCard> when i try fitHeaderCard = HeaderBlock.Find("BITPIX");

Comment: Of course. You're not passing [what the documentation says you should](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.find?view=netframework-4.7.2). You need a predicate, not a string. You should be able to use a lambda (`_ => { }`) as a stand-in. Something like, `fitHeaderCard = HeaderBlock.Find(item => item.keyword == "BITPIX");`.

Comment: *insert face palm*  as soon as I get back to my desk, I'll give this a try and update you with the result.

Comment: @KennethK. this worked exactly as you said it would, and the desired behavior is just what I wanted!

Thank you!  Wish I could give you answer points for the comment!

Comment: I'll write something up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Find` method of `List` [requires a predicate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.find?view=netframework-4.7.2)(i.e. a function that takes in an element, does some calculation on it, and returns a boolean). Right now you're passing a `string`. That's not a predicate. What you might do instead is create either a separate method, anonymous function, or lambda that matches what I just specified:

(separate method; could also be local function)

```
...

    //This is what I'm having trouble with
    public FitHeaderCard GetFitHeaderCard(string _keyword)
    {
        fitHeaderCard = HeaderBlock.Find(FilterByBitPix);
        fitHeaderCard = new FitHeaderCard(fitHeaderCard); // clone constructor
        return fitHeaderCard;
    }

    public FitHeaderCard FilterByBitPix(FitHeaderCard item)
    {
        return item.keyword == "BITPIX";
    }
}
```

OR (anonymous function)

```
...

    //This is what I'm having trouble with
    public FitHeaderCard GetFitHeaderCard(string _keyword)
    {
        fitHeaderCard = HeaderBlock.Find(delegate (FitHeaderCard item) { return item.keyword == "BITPIX"); };
        fitHeaderCard = new FitHeaderCard(fitHeaderCard); // clone constructor
        return fitHeaderCard;
    }
}
```

OR (lambda)

```
...

    //This is what I'm having trouble with
    public FitHeaderCard GetFitHeaderCard(string _keyword)
    {
        fitHeaderCard = HeaderBlock.Find(item => item.keyword == "BITPIX");
        fitHeaderCard = new FitHeaderCard(fitHeaderCard); // clone constructor
        return fitHeaderCard;
    }
}
```

Comment: I used the lambda technique (i omitted the clone constructor line).  The result is exactly what I needed for the logic calling the GetFitHeaderCard("BITPIX") method.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<FitHeaderCard> matches = HeaderBlock.Where(p=>p.SomePublicStringPropertyInYourObject.Contains(searchString));
```

You want to code with C#, my advice: learn linq queries ASAP. It is very powerful for extracting what you need from lists.

Comment: That code won't compile. `Where` doesn't return a `List`.

Comment: Yes, Kenneth is right. It returns IEnumerable which can be converted to a list by calling .ToList()

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have a `List<>`, there are a number of LINQ-based queries you can use to extract this information.  In your particular example, this is probably the simplest:

```
var returnValue = HeaderBlock.FirstOrDefault(hb => hb.keyword.Equals("BITPIX"))?.value;
```

As the name suggests `FirstOrDefault`, this will return either the first item it finds in the list that matches, or the default value (which in this case is `NULL` because it is a list of objects).

There are other LINQ extensions you could use, such as:

- `First`, which throws an exception  if it can't find the keword;

  `var first = HeaderBlock.FirstOrDefault(hb => hb.keyword.Equals("BITPIX")).value;`
- `Where`, which returns a collection;

  `var foundItems = HeaderBlock.Where(hb => hb.keyword.Equals("BITPIX"));`
- `Single`, which is similar to `First`, but will throw an exception if there is more than one;

  `var single = HeaderBlock.Single(hb => hb.keyword.Equals("BITPIX")).value;`
- and `SingleOrDefault`, which again is similar to `Single` but will return `NULL` if it can't find anything.

  `var singleOrDefault = HeaderBlock.SingleOrDefault(hb => hb.keyword.Equals("BITPIX"))?.value;`

LINQ is really important and incredibly powerful, and there is a lot of literature available to help you (admittedly, I personally found the official documentation quite hard to read, and hard to grasp the actual syntax in usage).